# JS Selenium access an element with no identifiers

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webautomation

trying to click an href nested inside an iframe and more divs and a table

the href has no id class or anything I know that can be used to access it

any ideas ?

[the html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XTGW.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath for that. Since you mentioned the href changes, you can use contain and enter the part of the href thats static.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'url')]")
```

Also make sure you focus on the iframe before trying to click this element, otherwise you will get no such element error.

```
driver.switchTo().frame('frame-id');
```

Comment: i tried using the xpath i never did before and i cant get it to work tho

Comment: maybe by looking at the image of the code you can help me find the correct xpath value

Comment: the problem is that everytime i run the code the href changes a bit

Comment: i edited my answer, you can use contains for that. Just enter the part of the href thats always stays the same. Something like 'https://accounts.stage-mycwt.com' should work for you.

Comment: Let me know if it works and don't forget to accept the answer if it did, so other people know your problem is solved :)